# Installing Bitcoin-Qt on Ubuntu

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. I have downloaded Bitcoin-Qt, but I don't think it has installed itself. The instructions say "download and install" the software, but I'm afraid I need instructions that are a little more specific. If you can tell me how to install the software it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Where did you get the software from? What steps have you done? etc

Comment: I got the software from this website (bitcoin.org). I downloaded it, but I'm not very knowledgeable about Ubuntu or programming. I found one page that gave me a string of magic jibberish to put in the DOS window, which I did, but it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: You're on bitcoin.stackexchange.com now, not bitcoin.org. I've edited your question to be more meaningful.

Answer (score 10):

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:luke-jr/bitcoincore
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install bitcoin

Comment: When I put in that second line of jibberish I get this:
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
donnie@donnie-amdnew:~$

I frequently run into the permission problem. Apparently, in Ubuntu, you have to get permission to do anything.

Comment: second and third commands also need sudo

Comment: if it worked you should mark the answer!!

Comment: If you guys don't even know basic package management of Ubuntu, maybe you should read up on that. It is essential.