# Why is bitcoin-qt not launching?  Using linuxmint-12-lisa

Tags: bitcoin-core

i'm using LinuxMint-12-lisa and installed bitcoin-qt as described

[Installing Bitcoin-Qt on Ubuntu](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/installing-bitcoin-on-ubuntu)

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt

bitcoin icon appeared to Application list and available to execute, but nothing happened after start. Please help

Comment: Can you post what, if anything, appeared in ~/.bitcoin after attempting to run bitcoin? What happens when you run bitcoin-qt -? in a terminal, or just bitcoin-qt? (Comment from Matt Corallo as requested)

Answer (score 1):

There is a bin folder that contains the binary. There are two folders in that folder, "32" and "64". You have to know what type of system your mint/computer is. It either a 32 bit system or 64 bit system. If you click on on a 32 bitcoin-qt on a 64 bit computer it will not start and vice versa.